# CSS width transition and hover

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to implement a slide show like menu with CSS. It's working fine except for transition. If transition is used the elements are not in sync anymore. Whole menu losing width if multiple elements are hovered in short time. Everything works fine if transition is removed.

Is there anything I have to be aware of when using CSS transitions and hover together? I thought a `transition-timing-function: linear;` would be enough to get width in sync. It seems like the transition is started early on the fading out element than fading in element.

Some technical notes about implementation:

It's a `ul` list. Menu items are represented as `li`. Selected menu item has a `selected`. This one is shown if there isn't any user interaction. The other ones are collapsed. If an element is hovered it's opened and all other ones are collapsed. There should be a transition effect when changing from collapsed to shown.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  /*
  * remove gaps between inline elements
  * https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/
  */
  font-size: 0;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*
  * Transition
  */
  transition: width 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  width: 50px;
}
ul li:hover,
ul li.selected,
ul:hover li.selected:hover {
  width: 564px;
}
ul:hover li.selected {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.3ker-ras-group.com/profil.html">
      <img src="http://www.3ker-ras-group.com/images/m_profil.jpg" alt="Unser Profil">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="selected">
    <a href="http://www.3ker-ras-group.com/referenzen.html">
      <img src="http://www.3ker-ras-group.com/images/m_referenzen_der_3ker_ras_group.jpg" alt="Referenzen der 3KER RAS GROUP">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.3ker-ras-group.com/jobs.html">
      <img src="http://www.3ker-ras-group.com/images/m_hoehenarbeiter_jobs.jpg" alt="Jobs für Höhenarbeiter">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.3ker-ras-group.com/shop-kletterbedarf.html">
      <img src="http://www.3ker-ras-group.com/images/m_kletterbedarf_shop.jpg" alt="Unser Shop für Kletterbedarf">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.3ker-ras-group.com/kontakt.html">
      <img src="http://www.3ker-ras-group.com/images/m_kontakt_zum_unternehmen.jpg" alt="Kontakt aufnehmen">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Trigger the issue by moving cursor fast from left to right. It occurs at least in Firefox and Chrome. Didn't tested safari, IE and edge.

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vj12qswz/3/
All elements should fit in one line. Adjust preview window width if necessary.

Comment: Is that a likely behaviour on the part of the user? Seems like an edge case.

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't think so. It occurs every time if a user skips one or more items. So if a user is on first item and is interested in third one he will hover over second one cause it's the fastest way and therefore trigger the issue.

Comment: Not sure there is anything you can do about then.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine if you use javascript to add a specific class on hover.

Probably best to add "onclick" event as well because hover not gonna work on touch devices.

Comment: Could you please share a working example? I updated the JSFiddle to use add/remove classes and it shows the same transition bug: https://jsfiddle.net/vj12qswz/33/

Comment: I don't see that on your fiddle.

Comment: But you can reproduce the issue in original provided CSS? If so please let me know which browser you are using. I could reproduce the issue even with jQuery changing classes in Firefox and Chrome.